# Notifications dropdown with TinyScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I'm relatively new to jQuery and am trying to learn best practices/design patterns with JavaScript. Came across [this link](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) and decided to try and put it to something useful.

So far I've made a notifications menu dropdown using [TinyScrollBar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) where the user can remove an individual notification. Once removed, the height of the dropdown updates until there are no more.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pSpBM/3/) is a demo of what I have so far.

I would like to know ways on how I can improve my JavaScript.

JS

```
var TEST = TEST || {};

/* Notifications */
TEST.notif = {};
TEST.notif._notifOpen = false;
TEST.notif._el = null;
TEST.notif._sum = 0;
TEST.notif._defaultVPHeight = 350;

TEST.notif.init = function(){

this._el = $('#notifications');

$('.notif-trigger').on('click',function(e){
    TEST.notif.toggleNotifications();
    return false;
});

// when you click outside the notification menu
// hide the notifications
$('html').on('click',function(e){
    if( TEST.notif._notifOpen ) {
        TEST.notif.hideNotifications();
    }
});

// set initial notifications scrollbar height
this._el.tinyscrollbar( {size: TEST.notif._defaultVPHeight} );
};

TEST.notif.showNotifications = function(){
var $el = this._el,
    $close = $('.notif-close'),
    $li = $('.notif-list li a');

// show notificatoins and update scrollbar position
$el.show().tinyscrollbar_update();

// stop propagation 
$li.on('click',function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });

// remove list-item 
$close.on('click', function(e){

    // store
    var liHeight, newH, overviewH;

    // store individual list-item height
    liHeight = $(this).parent().height();

    // remove the list-item you clicked
    $(this).parent().remove();

    // store the new height TEST the viewport
    newH = TEST.notif._defaultVPHeight - liHeight;

    // get height TEST actual contents
    overviewH = $('.overview').height();

    // set new defaultH
    TEST.notif._defaultVPHeight = newH;

    // update scrollbar
    $el.tinyscrollbar_update();

    // once scrollbar is disabled, start changing the viewport height
    if( $('#notifications .scrollbar').hasClass('disable') && $('.notif-list li').length > 1 ){
        $('#notifications .viewport').height( overviewH );
    } else if( $('.notif-list li').length == 1 ) {
        $('.notif-list li.empty').show();
    }

    return false;
});

this._notifOpen = true;
};


TEST.notif.hideNotifications = function(){
this._el.hide();
this._notifOpen = false;
};

TEST.notif.toggleNotifications = function(){
this._notifOpen ? this.hideNotifications() : this.showNotifications();
};

/* init */
$(document).ready(function(){
    TEST.notif.init();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From a once over:

- Review your comments, some of them just take up space and are not very valuable:

  ```
  // update scrollbar
  $el.tinyscrollbar_update();
  ```
- Indentation ( this might be because of copy pasting ) is off in your code, making it hard(er) to read
- `TEST.notif` is a mouthful, I would just go for `notifications`
- `_el`, `_sum`, `_defaultVPHeight` should all loose their underscore, they dont make sense. Also I would go either for the Spartan `e` or the full out `element`.
- `TEST.notif._notifOpen` -> why `notifOpen`, it's already part of an object called `notif`, just call it `open`
- Use lowerCamelCase consistently: `tinyscrollbar_update` -> `tinyScrollbarUpdate`

Other than that, your code is well structured and easy to follow.